# Data not getting read in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I'm using React JS on my front end to send data to my database as well as images to my server using NodeJS and PostgreSQL. It works fine sending data to the table albums and songs as well as the images to my server but when trying to access request.body.files.length as well as request.file.filename/req.file.etc. it gives me the errors of

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

&

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'filename' of undefined`

Although I'm able to access request.file and request.body.files earlier in my code as well request.body.files in my query.

request.file
[image]

request.body.files
[image]

Not being able to access `request.file.filename/etc.` in my last queries disables me from adding those values to my database

```
const addData = (request, response) => {
const uuid = uuidv4(); 
let album_id;

     db.pool.query('INSERT INTO albums (title, date, description, id) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) ON CONFLICT (id) DO NOTHING RETURNING *' , [request.body.title, request.body.date, request.body.description, uuid])
    .then(res => {
      album_id = res.rows[0].id;
      response.status(201).send({ message: "Success" });
      console.log('INSERT ' + res.rowCount);
      console.log(request.file)
      console.log(request.body.files)
      req_body_files = request.body.files;
    }).then(() => {
       const dbQueryPromises = [];
       for (let i = 0; i < request.body.files.length; i++) {
        dbQueryPromises.push(db.pool.query('INSERT INTO songs (id, name, link, index, album_id) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) ON CONFLICT (album_id, index) DO NOTHING RETURNING *', [uuidv4(), request.body.files[i].name, request.body.files[i].link, request.body.files[i].index, album_id]))
      }
        return Promise.all(dbQueryPromises);
        }).then(res => {
         console.log('Array of INSERT result for second insert: ');
         console.log(request.file);
    }).then(() => {
        db.pool.query(
        'INSERT INTO file (name, type, size, path, album_id) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) ON CONFLICT (album_id) DO NOTHING RETURNING *',
        [request.file.filename, request.file.mimetype, request.file.size, request.file.path, album_id]);
      }).then((res) => {
         console.log("INSERT INTO file(images) " + request.body.data);
      }).catch(error => console.log(error));



}
```

**index.js**

```
app.post('/albums', upload.single('file'), apiCall.addData);
```

So I'm not able to access `request.body.files.length` as well as `request.file.filename/etc.` in the last query. I have some ReactJS code as well but I don't think that's causing the issue.

Comment: Please mark in your code, at which point the error starts happening.

Comment: console.log("+++", request.body.files); right before your for loop inside then .then

Comment: @mkaatman it gives me the correct data

Comment: it also sends the data with `request.body.files[i]`

Comment: So if you run `console.log("+++", request.body.files.length);`  right before `for (let i = 0; i < request.body.files.length; i++) {` it returns the count? And then the for loop line it's undefined?

Comment: Yup. Very strange..

Comment: Although everything looks 100% correct, copy and paste the variable from the line where it's working and paste over the spot where it's not. Just. In. Case.

Comment: It's because on my front-end I'm making two requests and on one request it can't find `.length` of undefined because that's not being sent there and the second one can't find `req.file` because that's not being sent on one request.